# min-width works but min-height doesn't

Tags: html, css

I have react-image-slideshow slider in my web app. I'm trying to cover parent div with image but i certain situations, there is a little space left.
P.S I use `react-image-gallery`

Rendered HTML:

```css
.image-gallery-slide div{
  height: 200px;
}

.image-gallery-image{
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1" class="image-gallery-slide  center" role="button" style="transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">
   <div>
      <img class="image-gallery-image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/">
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

I want that image to cover parent div

Comment: `object-fit` is irrelevant on a div element

Comment: Also, your isolated example does work. In your snippet, change the height of `.image-gallery-slide div` and you'll see the image expand to fill the container.

Comment: height, instead min-height would be efficient if object-fit and height is also applied to img ;)

Comment: Use px instead of % - just find out how many pixels you image is in height.

Answer (score 1):

Height works a little bit differently than width in css. While percentage values for width will always grab the inherited width from the element's parent, that only works for the root element `html` when we're talking about height.

That means the parent div must have a defined numerical height, or be `html` itself. (That's why your isolated code snippet works, as stated in the comments, by the way)

One solution would be to use the `vh` (viewport height) unit and set `min-height: 100vh`. That's not supported by all browsers, though.

Other solution would be to set the parent's height, as stated before.

I'm pretty sure there are even more approaches.

Comment: vh is viewport height not vertical height

Answer (score 0):

Use the **px** unit and set min-height:200px